# What is the best way to iterate through lines in a CSV file?

Tags: robotframework

I try to iterate through lines in a `csv` file.

However, the library `https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-csvlibrary/` is not supported with `Python3`.

So, do you know another way to iterate on lines please ? My objective is to do something like:

```
@{lines}=    Get Lines      dataset.csv
:FOR    ${line}    IN     ${lines}
\     Log     ${line}[column1]
\     Log     ${line}[column2]
\     Log     ${line}[column3]
```

Thank you for your help and advice.

Comment: You can use map(lambda x: x....)

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres thanks. Could you give a example please?

Answer (score 2):

I found this way:

*Python*

```
def get_lines_from_csv(csv_path):
    data = []
    with open(csv_path, 'rt') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            data.append(row)
    return data
```

*Robotframework*

```
@{lines} =    Get Lines From Csv    ${DATAFILE_PATH}
${lines_length} =     Get Length    ${lines}
FOR    ${csv_row_index}    IN RANGE    2    ${lines_length}
\    @{currentLine}=    Set Variable    @{lines}[${csv_row_index}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but one kind of a solution.

```
@{lines}=    Get Lines      dataset.csv
:FOR    ${line}    IN     ${lines}
\     ${csv_row_as_a_list}=    Split String    ${line}     ,     
\     Log     ${csv_row_as_a_list}[1]
\     Log     ${csv_row_as_a_list}[2]
\     Log     ${csv_row_as_a_list}[3]
```

Comment: This will work only for a csv file where none of the values have a comma as part of its data (eg: `one,two,"three,foo", four`).